# How to convert the LocalDate to LocalDateTime without using atStartOfDay() function?

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate

In the request body only date is passed but in the backend as well as in the resource file we are having the type as DateTime. So is there anyway to change that date to DateTime by using some annotations or converter?

We cannot use atStartOfDay() function because, it will give cause some issues in some other places

Comment: "We cannot use atStartOfDay() function because, it will give cause some issues in some other places" What issues will it cause?

Comment: `.atTime(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT)` or `LocalDateTime.of(localDate, LocalTime.MIDNIGHT)`?

Comment: @Sweeper : we cannot use atStartOfDay() function because, same resource file will be used for get and create, if we try to use atStartOfDay() function, it will affect the functionality of get. (instead of giving the time fetched from DB it will give the start of the day time for all the dates in DB for the get)

Comment: @Sweeper : your second comment also gives the same problem, as I have mentioned above. I am searching for the solution with annotations or some formatter or converter, which will convert and give the date to time, if time is not there and will simply leave if time is there

Comment: A `LocalDate` has no concept of time, hence you need to specify a time when converting to a `LocalDateTime`. Where do you get this time?